# Is it possible to use Puppeteer with React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, puppeteer

I want to execute a script that'll grab some data from a website off of a form submit through React Native. Is this possible?

The idea is I submit a link on my iOS/Android (React Native) app, and then it will display the data back. I'm hoping that it will be pretty fast to grab the data too.

Comment: It's possible with puppeteer-web or puppeteer-core. You need to run the chrome server somewhere. IS that what you want?

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher Oh, I was trying to use node and express, perhaps? So I think I was able to do it, using express to connect to backend, and then run the puppeteer. Will it have issues if there's multiple users trying to request `puppeteer.launch();` or `.newPage()`?

Comment: Scaling is altogether a different problem. Think every single .newPage as a new tab, and think how many tabs your server can handle. Also make sure one user does not get cookies from another user (which happens with .newPage).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for that 
**onmessage** function in WebView
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#onmessage

```
<WebView

                    source={{uri: yourUrl}}
                    onMessage={(event)=>{
                        let message  = event.nativeEvent.data;
                        console.log(message)

                    }}

                    onError={(e) => {
                        console.warn('error occured', e)
                }}/>
```

Web-end js code will be like

```
  document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("focus", function() {  
  var data = {
      type: "OnFocusEvent",
      message : "OnFocusEvent"
  };
  window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({data}),"*");
});

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("blur", function() {  
  var data = {
      type: "OnBlurEvent",
      message : "OnBlurEvent"
  };
  window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({data}),"*");
});
```